# How to format write protected SD card

Tags: readonly, sd-card

I want to format my SD card using Ubuntu, for this I follow [this tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_6080534_format-sd-card-ubuntu.html)

After typing `df` command , I got list of storage devices.From here I can see my SD card name is `/dev/sdb5` so I replace `/dev/sdb1` with `/dev/sdb5` in all next commands.Now `umount` command works fine but after this when I type `mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/sdb5`
 I am getting these lines:

```
mkdosfs 3.0.12 (29 Oct 2011)
mkdosfs: unable to open /dev/sdb5: Read-only file system
```

so, how to fix this.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your SD card has a write protect switch on the side?

Comment: I tried to format it through windows also, there it shows its a read only drive

Comment: He is asking if there is a small physical button/switch on SD card which forces read-only.

Comment: no, there is no such thing

Comment: Actually I have install Debian in it for beaglebone black and was using it for last 10 days, now I want to put Ubuntu in it, for this when tried to format it , I got this problem, may be something happens because of debian

Comment: If it doesn't work in Linux and it doesn't work in Windows, it's presumably a hardware problem. You generally can't fix hardware problems in software.

Comment: Almost definitely there is a physical problem with the card - such as a lifted contact or similar - and the card's embedded controller has configured itself to allow only reads. If you wish to pursue it further, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3GDPwIuRKI) is an in-depth look at sd-cards inside and out.

Comment: I got the solution for this problem through windows 7, here is the link:-
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39R-r9eYuEI
so I am sure there will be a solution in Linux as well

Comment: Have you tried to use for example `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` and just delete all partitions and recreate them?

Comment: @tabish I tried the instructions from the youtube video that you linked in the comment as the one which solved your problem. It didn't help in my case, but after going though all steps, I believe that `fdisk` in Debian or Ubuntu would do as good as `diskpart` on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The card is now useless, hope that you don't have any important data on it.  I had the same happen to 3 different cards.  I have tried everything I found out there, whether it works on Linux, Mac, or Windows, and nothing works.

Answer (score 11):

1. I assume you (your unix user) owns the device or at least has sufficient permissions on it (for example if you are root).
2. If the command `lsblk -o NAME,RO` shows your device as read only (RO=1), you can try to execute `hdparm -r 0 /dev/sdb5`. This disables the read only flag in the kernel (according to `man hdparm`).

**Additional info:**

These steps helped me with a micro SD card that should not have been read only (micro SD cards have no "lock" switch but my adapter did not have one either and was recognized as locked). I found this solution [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/289278-32-remove-write-protection-micro-card).

Wikipedia explaines that the physical lock switch on SD cards can but need not be respected by the software: [link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Card_security)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use that sd card in a phone if possible and format it. I have run into this issue previously and the phone trick did it. But most probably the card has become useless as this is a very common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same problem and after striving for it for a long time now, I have finally come up with a solution.

There are some SD cards available in the market with microSD input. i.e. micrSD card fits into the SD card.

You can use it disable the lock switch in the SD card and format...
works like a charm.